# awk concatenate strings till contain substring

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a `awk` script from [this](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/05/awk-join-or-merge-lines-on-finding.html) example:

```
awk '/START/{if (x) print x; x="";}{x=(!x)?$0:x","$0;}END{print x;}' file
```

Here's a sample file with lines:

```
$ cat file
START
1
2
3
4
5
end
6
7
START
1
2
3
end
5
6
7
```

So I need to stop concatenating when destination string would contain `end` word, so the desired output is:

```
START,1,2,3,4,5,end
START,1,2,3,end
```

Comment: Your question doesn't contain a question.

Comment: Nevertheless, 5 users gave me an answer to it. So, it seems like it's OK for most of people, if it doesn't contain the question mark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short **`Awk`** solution (though it will check for `/end/` pattern twice):

```
awk '/START/,/end/{ printf "%s%s",$0,(/^end/? ORS:",") }' file
```

The output:

```
START,1,2,3,4,5,end
START,1,2,3,end
```

---

- `/START/,/end/` - *range* pattern

> A *range pattern* is made of two patterns separated by a comma, in the
>   form `‘begpat, endpat’`. It is used to match ranges of consecutive
>   input records. The first pattern, `begpat`, controls where the range
>   begins, while `endpat` controls where the pattern ends.

- `/^end/? ORS:","` - set delimiter for the current item within a range

Comment: Never use range expressions as they make trivial scripts very slightly briefer or require complete rewrites or duplicate conditions (e.g. testing for "end" twice in this case) when the requirements get just the tiniest bit more interesting. Always use a flag variable instead, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47796423/1745001

Comment: @EdMorton, yes, I realize that it will check for `/end/` pattern twice. Let it just be an alternative approach in addition to "flag"-based approach. I won't call my suggested approach as the only best one ... the other answers are good enough

Answer (score 4):

here is another `awk`

```
$ awk '/START/{ORS=","} /end/ && ORS=RS; ORS!=RS' file

START,1,2,3,4,5,end
START,1,2,3,end
```

Note that `/end/ && ORS=RS;` is shortened form of `/end/{ORS=RS; print}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '/START/{p=1; x=""} p{x = x (x=="" ? "" : ",") $0} /end/{if (x) print x; p=0}' file

START,1,2,3,4,5,end
START,1,2,3,end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, similar to answers in [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns/)

```
$ awk '/START/{ORS=","; f=1} /end/{ORS=RS; print; f=0} f' ip.txt
START,1,2,3,4,5,end
START,1,2,3,end
```

- this doesn't need a buffer, but doesn't check if `START` had a corresponding `end`
- `/START/{ORS=","; f=1}` set ORS as `,` and set a flag (which controls what lines to print)
- `/end/{ORS=RS; print; f=0}` set ORS to newline on ending condition. Print the line and clear the flag
- `f` print input record as long as this flag is set

Answer (score 0):

Since we seem to have gone down the rabbit hole with ways to do this, here's a fairly reasonable approach with GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='end' -v OFS=',' 'RT{$0=gensub(/.*(START)/,"\\1",1); $NF=$NF OFS RT; print}' file
START,1,2,3,4,5,end
START,1,2,3,end
```